# Rails Modal Popup after create action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, popup, modal-dialog

I have a simple vote action in my rails app and i would like a modal popup (like the on in twitter bootstrap) to show after a successful create action. I have a modal view partial, a respond_to block that accepts .js and a create.js.erb file which should in theory be displayed when the create action is called, if im not mistaken?

I just don't quite understand how to wire all of these things together, ( also i assume the javascript is incorrect) any tips would be great thanks!

controller.rb

```
def create
    @vote = Vote.new(params[:vote])
    respond_to do |format|
    if @vote.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back,  notice: "Thank you for voting! why not Tweet your vote?" }
      format.js  <!--should there be a call to a specific file here?-->
    else
      flash[:error] = "please try again"
      redirect_to :back
    end
    end
  end
end
```

votes/info.html.erb

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Thanks for voting!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Why not tweet your selection?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

votes/create.js.erb

```
$(".modal").html(<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'votes/info' %>);
$(".modal").show();
```

vote _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([Vote.new(hotel_id: hotel.id)]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :hotel_id %>
    <%= f.submit "Vote", class: "btn-large btn-info" %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Quotes on `$(".modal")`?

Comment: Ah yes that would help lol, question edited, modal still isnt showing tho? do you think the divs the correct method for selecting the modal div class?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us votes/new.html.erb but I think the problem is that `<div class="modal hide fade">` needs to be in that file, not the partial. Also, ensure that the partial file name begins with an underscore, "_info.html.erb".

Comment: Hi Tom, Ive added the new form in the edit. Where would you place the div class modal in that file? would it be like :html => { render partial "votes/info" } do |f| ?

Comment: You can put it at the bottom but it really doesn't matter since it's either hidden or modal. Just the div, nothing else. The js.erb file will render and insert the partial's html.

Comment: Ive put the div at the bottom of the form but still no show, could the page re rendering upon creation of a new object prevent the modal from showing?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I wonder if you'd be better off with a "votes/thanks" view rather than a modal. So after a successful vote, redirect_to "thanks".

Comment: would defo be easier to code, it would be nice to stay on the same page as you can vote for a number of things as its not just a one off